# C++/CLI Disposable value class

Tags: .net, c++-cli, dispose, idisposable, value-type

Struct in C# (value type) can implement IDisposable, how can I achieve same thing in C++/CLI?

```
public value class MyStruct : public System::IDisposable
{
public:
    // value types cannot contain user-defined special member functions
    virtual ~MyStruct()
    {
        Console::WriteLine("DisposeCalled"); 
    }

    // a finalizer can only be a member of a reference type
    !MyStruct()
    {
        Console::WriteLine("DisposeCalled"); 
    }

    // this method is reserved within a managed class   
    virtual void Dispose()
    {
        Console::WriteLine("DisposeCalled"); 
    }       

    // 'Dispose' is not a member of 'System::IDisposable' (seriously?)
    virtual void DisposeMe() = System::IDisposable::Dispose
    {
        Console::WriteLine("DisposeCalled"); 
    }
};
```

None of my attempts were successful (I've tried one by one). Removing 'virtual' does not help.

Comment: You can't, the C++/CLI spec is pretty unapologetic about it.  See ECMA 372, chapter 22.3.4.  You can inherit IDisposable but the compiler auto-generates Dispose() and it will be empty.  This is not a loss, value classes should only ever be very simple structs with no special semantics for copying and disposal.

Comment: @HansPassant: Even if structures should not have a `Dispose` method *that does anything*, it can sometimes be helpful for structures to implement interfaces that inherit `IDisposable` if the structure itself doesn't need cleanup (but other implementations of the interface do).

Comment: @HansPassant Can you make it an answer?